# simplifying a json list to the unique dict items

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, unique

New to python (could use php as well).. Searched various sites/SO.. and still have a mental block.

Got a json, and trying to figure out how to take a list that contains dicts and create a resulting list that has a unique set of the dicts..

As an exmple, the following is the test list:

```
[{"pStart1a": {"termVal":"1122","termMenu":"CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_STRM","instVal":"OSUSI",
"instMenu":"CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_INSTITUTION","goBtn":"CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SSR_PB_SRCH",
"pagechk":"CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SSR_PB_SRCH","nPage":"CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SSR_PB_CLASS_SRCH"},
"pSearch1a":  
{"chk":"CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_MON","srchbtn":"DERIVED_CLSRCH_SSR_EXPAND_COLLAPS"}},
 {"pStart1":""},
 {"pStart1a":{"termVal":"1122","termMenu":"CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_STRM","instVal":"OSUSI",
 "instMenu":"CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_INSTITUTION","goBtn":"CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SSR_PB_SRCH",
 "pagechk":"CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SSR_PB_SRCH","nPage":"CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SSR_PB_CLASS_SRCH"},
 "pSearch1a":
 {"chk":"CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_MON","srchbtn":"DERIVED_CLSRCH_SSR_EXPAND_COLLAPS"}},
 {"pStart1":""}]
```

Trying to get the following, list of unique dicts, so there aren't duplicate dicts.

```
[
  {"pStart1a": 
  {"termVal":"1122","termMenu":"CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_STRM","instVal":"OSUSI",
   "instMenu":"CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_INSTITUTION","goBtn":"CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SSR_PB_SRCH",
   pagechk":"CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SSR_PB_SRCH","nPage":"CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SSR_PB_CLASS_SRCH"},
  "pSearch1a":
  {"chk":"CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_MON","srchbtn":"DERIVED_CLSRCH_SSR_EXPAND_COLLAPS"}},
  {"pStart1":""}]
```

I was considering iterating through the initial list, copying each dict into a new list, and doing a basic comparison, adding the next dict if it's not in the new list.. is there another/better way?

thanks

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using Python's inbuilt json library?

Comment: Is it practical problem? What will you do with the result list? Maybe you can use different format or some simplification to data?

Answer (score 3):

If the `oldlist` contains list of dicts in Python (for example, as a result of json.loads(jsonstring) ), then new list can be constructed by something like this:

```
encountered = set()
newlist = []
for i in oldlist:
    repr_i = repr(i)
    if repr_i in encountered:
       continue
    encountered.add(repr_i)
    newlist.append(i)

print newlist
```

Some other function can be used instead of repr, for example, hash digest of repr.

Comment: You can make this a little more efficient by storing the result of `repr(i)` in a variable.

Comment: As it stands, this is not guaranteed to work: if two items have the same hash value, a different `repr` can be produced depending on the order the items were entered in the dict.

Comment: I agree with this. Some special recursive function to traverse nested dicts/lists, ordering keys of dicts, is needed.

Comment: As a possbile workaround on python >= 2.7, you can use `object_pairs_hook` argument of `json.loads` seted to `OrderedDict()`, and then use `json.dumps` instead `repr` to compare dicts. But it's total overkill :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach -- using `list(set(your_list_of_dicts))` won't work because Python dictionaries are mutable and not hashable (that is, they don't implement `__hash__`). This is because Python can't guarantee that the hash of a dictionary won't change after you insert it into a `set` or `dict`.

However, in your case, since you (don't seem to be) modifying the data at all, you can compute your own hash, and use this along with a dictionary to relatively easily find the unique JSON objects without having to do a full recursive comparison of each dictionary to the others.

First, we need a function to compute a hash of the dictionary. Rather than trying to build our own hash function, let's use one of the built-in ones from [`hashlib`](http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html):

```
def dict_hash(d):
    out = hashlib.md5()
    for key, value in d.iteritems():
        out.update(unicode(key))
        out.update(unicode(value))
    return out.hexdigest()
```

(Note that this relies on `unicode(...)` for each of your values returning something unique -- if you have custom classes in the dictionaries whose `__unicode__` returns something like "MyClass instance", this will fail or will require modification. Also, in your example, your dictionaries are flat, but I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader how to expand this solution to work with dictionaries that contain other dicts or lists.)

Since `dict_hash` returns a string, which is immutable, you can now use a dictionary to find the unique elements:

```
uniques_map = {}
for d in list_of_dicts:
    uniques[dict_hash(d)] = d
unique_dicts = uniques_map.values()
```

Comment: hi dcrosta... trying to implement/test/learn what you posted.. what's the definition of the "uniques"   is that a list/dict? i would assume it's not a list as the output of the "dict_hash" is a str...    thanks

Comment: `uniques` is a dictionary, yes -- but calling `.values()` on a dictionary gives you a list of the values (not keys) from the dictionary. since we store the original dictionary `d` as the value for each key (where the key is the hash), then `.values()` gives you a list of the dictionaries which had unique hashes (i.e. the unique dictionaries from the original `list_of_dicts`)

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question right, you can try this:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

json_string = """[{"pStart1a": {"termVal":"1122","termMenu":"CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_STRM","instVal":"OSUSI",
"instMenu":"CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_INSTITUTION","goBtn":"CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SSR_PB_SRCH",
"pagechk":"CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SSR_PB_SRCH","nPage":"CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SSR_PB_CLASS_SRCH"},
"pSearch1a":
{"chk":"CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_MON","srchbtn":"DERIVED_CLSRCH_SSR_EXPAND_COLLAPS"}},
 {"pStart1":""},
 {"pStart1a":{"termVal":"1122","termMenu":"CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_STRM","instVal":"OSUSI",
 "instMenu":"CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_INSTITUTION","goBtn":"CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SSR_PB_SRCH",
 "pagechk":"CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SSR_PB_SRCH","nPage":"CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SSR_PB_CLASS_SRCH"},
 "pSearch1a":
 {"chk":"CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_MON","srchbtn":"DERIVED_CLSRCH_SSR_EXPAND_COLLAPS"}},
 {"pStart1":""}]
"""

result = {}
for dct in json.loads(json_string):
    for key, value in dct.iteritems():
        result[key] = value

pprint(result)
```

Output:

```
 {u'pSearch1a': {u'chk': u'CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_MON',
                u'srchbtn': u'DERIVED_CLSRCH_SSR_EXPAND_COLLAPS'},
 u'pStart1': '',
 u'pStart1a': {u'goBtn': u'CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SSR_PB_SRCH',
               u'instMenu': u'CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_INSTITUTION',
               u'instVal': u'OSUSI',
               u'nPage': u'CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SSR_PB_CLASS_SRCH',
               u'pagechk': u'CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SSR_PB_SRCH',
               u'termMenu': u'CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_STRM',
               u'termVal': u'1122'}}
```

**EDIT**

Note, it converts your list of dicts, to dict. Maybe it will be easier to do further operations on it.

It's also possible, to convert `result` to list:

```
list_result = [{key:value} for key, value in result.iteritems()]
```

**NOTE 2**

Comparision is based on dict keys, and it extracts nested values to root level. Don't know if it's accessible for OP. Probably you **shouldn't** use this solution. Anyway it's 8 times faster (on this data) than using `repr()` to compare dicts.

Comment: This answer is plain wrong. THe result should be a list of unique dicts as  specified by OP.

Comment: @RomanSusi, anyway, i think this solution has the right to life, because operations on dict is easier than on list of dicts.

Comment: operations can be easier, but your solution is not for the OP's problem, I guess.

Comment: @RomanSusi, you are right. Added way to get list of dicts to answer.

Comment: Ok. However, its still wrong: its nowhere said that dicts have exactly one key and also that two dicts are equal only based on the equality of keys, not values...

Comment: Thank you @RomanSusi. Added another note to answer. So, it not solves OP's problem, but tries to propose another way of handling this data.